# Clarify the meaning of the Generalist badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-description, generalist-badge

So here's the description of Generalist:

> Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

Has anyone ever realized just how ambiguous that is? Here are the ways it could be interpreted (assume "answer" means it can't be CW):

- Achieve 15 tag score in 20 of the 40 most-used tags (this is what it is)
- Answer questions across 20 of the 40 most-used tags with 15 or more total score across *all* of those answers
- Achieve 15 tag score in 20 of *your own* top 40 tags (this is what I first thought it was)
- Answer questions with 15+ score *for each answer* that covers 20 of your own/the site's top 40 tags

I think that it should be changed to something like this:

> Reach 15 tag score in half of the 40 most-used tags

Even better would be to add a 10<sup>th</sup> row (yes there are 9, at least in my browser) to the first page of tags, so that instead of "40 most-used tags" it could be "first page of tags".

Comment: On its own, "Reach 15 tag score..." makes no sense.

Comment: @RobertCartaino do you have a better idea?

Comment: The more confusing thing about this badge is you can't get it until the top 40 tags are tagged in at least 200 questions each.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, but your suggestion does not solve it. For example, it does not avoid your second interpretation.

Rather, I suggest:

> For 20 of the site’s top 40 tags, provide non-wiki answers amounting to a total score of 15 in each.

Unless I am mistaken, this should avoid all described ambiguities.

Furthermore I suggest to mention the site-wide threshold, which is always a source of disappointment:

> (Only awarded if the site has 40 tags with at least 200 questions each.)

Alternatively, just [get rid of this threshold altogether](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127689/255554).

---

> Even better would be to add a 10th row (yes there are 9, at least in my browser) to the first page of tags, so that instead of "40 most-used tags" it could be "first page of tags".

I disagree. I do not want to go to another site to understand the badge. Moreover, this introduces another ambiguity: Does this refer to the [general tag overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) or [my personal one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/255554/wrzlprmft?tab=tags). Yes, the latter makes little sense when you think about it, but then so do many of your possible interpretations of the badge’s current wording.

Comment: All good points. I think you've earned the bounty :)