# Are there really people who spend all day going through StackOverflow, closing people's questions, and costing them points?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, down-votes

What is the "subjective" tag for, if not to ask subjective questions?  "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." sounds Subjective to me.  Who are these lovely people?  Is SO meant to be a grim, colorless place?

Comment: The [subjective] tag is used to identify subjective questions, *not* justify them. For a subjective question to stay on SO, it really needs more substance past that, it can't remain on SO just because it's subjective.

Comment: Getting answers to your questions should be the primary concern, not amassing points.

Comment: BTW - voting to close doesn't code anyone any points. Down-voting does.

Comment: Is there a list of acceptable questions somewhere?  I read through the FAQ, and I don't remember hearing about this (well, it *does* say "Avoid asking questions that are subjective," but then there's the "Subjective" tag).  It also says "Be nice," but apparently you don't have to to gain authority. :(

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19113/do-we-really-need-the-subjective-tag-and-is-it-commonly-mis-used and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag

Comment: @Chris: If closing is the first step toward deleting (and it should be for some questions) then it leads to an eventual loss of rep...once the question has been deleted and a recalc occurs.

Comment: @dmckee Not many people get that many upvotes on closed questions, especially the ones that should be deleted. In fact, the ones deserving of deletion tend to attract downvotes more so they'd actually be *earning* reputation from the fact (but in the end, it's actually a net result of 0 for that question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is SO meant to be a grim, colorless place?

No. You're thinking of Meta.

BTW, welcome to Meta...

Comment: From the FAQ:  "If you want to ... discuss how Stack Overflow works, please do not ask it here – visit our meta-discussion site."  Where discussion is also not allowed.  Oh well, thanks for making my day that much worse.

Comment: @orbfish: (a) This is a bit of a joke answer, (b) Meta is a discussion site due to the nature of what's asked here, (c) while you have a legitimate question, the way it was presented here could have been far less hostile.

Comment: @orbfish Discussion is absolutely allowed on Meta, it's one of the 'required tags' that all questions must have.

Comment: Jon Seigel - apparently it's not a legitimate suggestion, since I'm getting slapped down here as well.  Hostility is a natural response to aggression.

Comment: @orbfish: oddly enough, aggression is also a natural response to hostility... But anyway, I was referring to the lack of color in the Meta palette. You can absolutely discuss SO here, though if your thread looks like more of a rant you may find it shut down.

Comment: It's closed already.  Why do people keep downvoting when it's closed, doesn't that keep it from showing up and muddying the waters or whatever?

Answer (score 4):

Your question: [What Should Be The Punishment for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160322/what-should-be-the-punishment-for-this) was a great question, *for a discussion forum*.

Stack Overflow is the place to get your programming questions answered, not a place to chew the fat.  You can even see it in the way the site is structured: It's really hard to have a conversation, but really easy to ask a question and have *n* people answer that question.

Comment: You're a real geek! I liked the *`n` people*  thing haha...