# Tagging spam / offensive questions

Tags: discussion, tags, spam

Do we have recommended tags for obvious spam or offensive questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262101/java-thread-java-threadjava-threadjava-thread-closed)? For now I retagged it to [spam] just to get it out of the [java] view, but then I saw, that the [spam] tag is used for serious questions concerning spam too.

Removing all tags is not possible so even spam messages need at least one tag...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just flag it for moderator attention and it will be deleted, no need to go changing the tags

Comment: The question was closed, flagged, now even locked and deleted. But it was one of those rare questions that could be put just out of sight.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, questions that will be uncontroversially deleted aren't a big concern.  (Delete votes can be cast two days after closing.)

They should, however, still be tagged appropriately – plus what appears uncontroversial to me and you maybe actually isn't, and some questions (i.e. not this one) might end up staying.  Tagging [java] does little harm here, as the tag is so popular that this question will get lost in it, but [[untagged]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) is a candidate just because the system requires at least one tag.  (I've been planning to use [untagged] for exactly this situation, but haven't yet found a situation where I could think of nothing else.)

In general, tags are inappropriate for the intention or purpose of the poster rather than the content (["meta tags"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag)), with how the question should be closed (e.g. [offtopic]), and where the question should be moved (e.g. [belongs-on-*]).

Comment: [untagged] is a nice idea. That's close to my first intention to just remove all tags, because no programming-related tag was appropriate (which isn't possible). Usually (~99.5%) I just flag the message and leave it alone. This is really just for some really rare oaccasions.