# Should spam be tagged as [spam]?

Tags: discussion, tags, spam, meta-tags

There's a related question about editing the *text* of spam: [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/336163). I've always understood this to include any sort of edits on a spam post, including tag edits. The tag exert for the Stack Overflow [[spam]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) tag includes an explicit warning

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG ON QUESTIONS THAT ARE SPAM, we have a special flag for that!

I recently noticed that an [obvious spam post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/42141/10448) on ExpressionEngine Answers SE was treated exactly the way it is not supposed to be treated on Stack Overflow - a 3000+ rep user has retagged the question as [spam] and voted to close it seven hours after it was posted.

So,

Should questions that are spam be retagged as [spam] in addition to flagging as spam?

This is not the same question as [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/336163) as that question is about editing out the text of spammy advertisements. This question is about leaving the text as-is and retagging the question as [spam], presumably to adjust its visibility on the site or bring it to the attention of users who might be interested in flagging it as spam.

Comment: No, spam needs to be flagged and beyond that left alone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dilemma after someone else edits a spam post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306459/282094)

Comment: A more relevant duplicate is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57371/323179

Comment: Laurel's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363716/should-spam-be-tagged-as-spam#comment1213596_363716) might be grounds to reopen this question. In [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57371/282094) it is asked if it's OK to remove the only tag (since having one tag is mandatory) and replace it with another, to keep the unwanted post out of everyone's feed. --- In ***that*** case it wasn't retagged to bring it to some people's attention (as is presumed in this question),  it was retagged to remove it from spamming people who are watching the tag that was replaced.

Answer (score 14):

No, Spam needs to be flagged. Period.

> [image: Flag link and popup I am flagging to report this question as ... first option "Spam" selected]

There is no need to

- add a tag
- edit
- close vote
- down vote
- leave a comment

Users doing that should be told they are wasting their and our time. If posts linger for too long, jump in chat, either the per site chat room, [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) or [the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

Comment: I sometimes leave a comment saying “**This is spam, so flag it as spam!**” for cases where it’s apparently not obvious enough, e.g. posts that stick around for hours and accumulate close votes instead of quickly being deleted as spam.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah, I see those as well. better do a "still live" in Charcoal HQ and star the Smokey report.

Comment: Please flag it as spam. Do not pass Go. Do not collect 200 reputation.

Comment: One should probably jump in Charcoal HQ anyway to check of the spam has been caught.